# I have installed jasmine but test is unable to run always says No specs found

Tags: javascript, jasmine

i have installed `jasmine` by `$npm install -g jasmine` then i have initiated  it by `$jasmine init`  it created **spec/support** i have placed my `test.spec.js` in `spec/support/test.spec.js`

**test.spec.js**

```
var a = 100;

var b = 200;

describe("A suite", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

**my jasmine.json look like this**

```
{
"spec_dir": "spec",

"spec_files": [
"*/[sS]pec.js"
],

"helpers": [
"helpers/*/.js"
],

"stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,

"random": false
}
```

**now i wanted to test the test.spec.js by**

> $ [by running]      jasmine

always gives   **No specs found**

please help me thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: In `spec_files`, try adding this: `support/**/*[sS]pec.js`.

Comment: yes it works thanks alot @31piy

Comment: @31piy, one help from you, im not getting any message on passed `suite` or `test`. but getting on `failed` tests.  **Question:** how would i get `message` on passed test